# Objective C: Displaying Unicode characters

Tags: objective-c, string, ios

How would I display ∫ which is `&#8747;` as a symbol? I'm trying to display the integral sign in an NSString

Comment: Potentially off-topic, if you just want to type it into a string (rather than convert it in-line), you can use the [character viewer](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8164.html) to obtain it and then copy/paste.

Comment: That works just as well. I didn't even think about that. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the laziest way is sufficient. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read the following post by  [Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/01/advanced-drawing-using-appkit.html) , specially, the section titled `The floral heart adornment`. in the post, he creates an icon by code, and draws a floral heart(❦) by using a NSGlyph.

Comment: matt creates amazing tutorials.